# String pointer array in C and strcpy

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, strcpy

```
#define null "null" //its declared on top

int hash_size=100;
char *hash_table[hash_size];

int i;

for(i=0;i<hash_size;i++){
    strcpy(hash_table[i],null);// it doesn't works. WHY!
    //hash_table[i]=null; it works
}
```

i created a string pointer array. And i want to assign all elements with "null". But strcpy function doesn't works. Why?

Comment: #define null "null"     what the hell is this?

Comment: Where's the allocation?

Comment: thanks. i change my question. i want to make an string array like this: hash_table[0]-->"sunday"                                                                        hash_table[1]-->"monday" how to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only created an array pointers. But those pointers don't point to any valid memory - they are uninitialized. This is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The macro `null` doesn't make much sense either. If you want to initialize the pointer to NULL pointer then you can simply do:

```
char *hash_table[hash_size] = {0};
```

or if you really want each pointer to point to the string literal `"null"` then you can assign it:

```
for(i=0;i<hash_size;i++){
    hash_table[i]=null;
}
```

The assignment works because each of the pointers in the array is simply pointing at the string literal and point to the *same* string literal too.

If you want to be able to *modify* the memory that the pointers point to then you need to allocate memory:

```
for(i=0;i<hash_size;i++){
    hash_table[i] = malloc(sizeof("null"));
    if (hash_table[i]) { 
       */ error */
    }
    strcpy(hash_table[i],null);
}
```

And [`free()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) the pointers in a similar loop once you are done.

Answer (score 2):

`hash_table` is an array of pointers BUT you have not initialized them to point anywhere. You have not initialized the pointers in the array of pointers.

You can say

```
hash_table[i] = null;
```

and that will work.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that the following way

```
#define null "null" //its declared on top

int hash_size=100;
char *hash_table[hash_size];

int i;

char *p = null;

for(i=0;i<hash_size;i++){
    hash_table[i] = p;
}
```

In this case all elements of hash_table would point to the same string literal `"null"`.

You may not copy the string literal because 1) elements of the array are not initialized and 2) do not point to memory extents large enough to store a copy of the string literal.